# Angularjs radio button validation inside form is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing web application. I have 4 radio button. I am trying to validate radio buttons. By default none of the radio box should be checked. On clicking on submit if none of the radio button is not checked then i want to display error message.

```
        <form name="payment" novalidate>
                <fieldset ng-disabled="paymentform">
                  <div class="upload-button-container">
                            <div class="upload-button bank button1">
                                <div class="upload-button-icon">
                                    <label for="visa" class="visa">
                                        <img src="images/visa.png">
                                        <input type="radio" id="visa" name="selector" ng-model="card">
                                        <span class="selector-visa"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="upload-button bank button2">
                                <div class="upload-button-icon">
                                    <label for="americanexpress" class="americanexpress">
                                        <img src="images/americanexpress.png">
                                        <input type="radio" id="americanexpress" name="selector" ng-model="card">
                                        <span class="selector-americanexpress"></span>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
     <div class="button-container margin-top80">
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'BACK' | translate }}" class="brown-button">
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'NEXT' | translate }}" class="blue-button" ng-click="makepayment()">
 </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to validate here in javascript file.

```
$scope.makepayment = function () {
                if($scope.card!=null)
                {

                }else
                {
                    toastr.error($filter('translate')('Error Occured', ''));
                }
            }
```

Above code always returns null. May I know what i am missing in the above code? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: both are in the same controller?

Comment: Thank you. Yeah..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a value attribute in radio input tag.

> The value to which the ngModel expression should be set when selected. Note that value only supports string values, i.e. the scope model needs to be a string, too. Use ngValue if you need complex models (number, object, ...).